# Local only sendmail that delivers all mail to a directory

Tags: postfix, localhost, sendmail

I have a development Ubuntu Server (12.04.1) VM that I use to develop php sites and e-commerce sites (like Magento etc).

Because this is for development purposes, and I need to test with e-mail addresses other than my own, I need a way for the sendmail command to accept a mail but not actually deliver it, but rather archive is somewhere where I can look at it.

What is the easiest way to install a mail server such that the sendmail command routes ALL mail to a local directory? i.e. I do NOT want any mail to be delivered to the internet.

I tried the steps discussed in this question ( [SMTP server to deliver ALL mail to user@localhost](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28850/smtp-server-to-deliver-all-mail-to-userlocalhost)), but it doesn't seem to work - I get an error message in my (local) mailbox telling me that it cannot deliver my test message (e.g. someone@gmail.com)

Answer (score 8):

To answer my own question, using postfix this is possible. You have to do two things:

1. Add the configuration options discussed in [SMTP server to deliver ALL mail to user@localhost](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28850/smtp-server-to-deliver-all-mail-to-userlocalhost), add the following to your /etc/postfix/main.cf file:

   ```
   luser_relay = MYLOCALUSER@localhost
   local_recipient_maps =
   ```
2. Using the following answer on serverfault ( https://serverfault.com/questions/133190/host-wildcard-subdomains-using-postfix), I added the following (note that you need the postfix-pcre package installed):

   In /etc/postfix/main.cf:

   ```
    mydestination = pcre:/etc/postfix/mydestinations
   ```

   In /etc/postfix/mydestinations

   ```
   /.*/         ACCEPT
   ```

This will deliver ALL mail that postfix handles to the configured local user defined in #1, so don't use this for anything other than development.

Answer (score 6):

> "Because this is for development purposes, and I need to test with e-mail addresses other than my own, I need a way for the sendmail command to accept a mail but not actually deliver it, but rather archive is somewhere where I can look at it."

You'll still need to deliver it.  You just need to override "where" it's delivered.

> "What is the easiest way to install a mail server such that the sendmail command routes ALL mail to a local directory? i.e. I do NOT want any mail to be delivered to the internet."

This can actually be done using only the default postfix installation package (no need for postfix-pcre).

1.) Following a tutorial [here](https://www.opensourcery.com/blog/chad-granum/local-only-postfix-testing), edit 2 lines in the `/etc/postfix/master.cf` file to prevent any mail from being delivered externally (it gets stuck in the local mail queue):

```
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       local
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       local
```

2.)  Create a file in `/etc/postfix` called `virtual`.  Place the following line within that file, replacing `<USERNAME>` with the local user account name you want all mail to be delivered to:

```
/.*/    <USERNAME>
```

3.)  Run the following command to create the correct database file for postfix to look-up this new "virtual alias map".  The new, autogenerated database file will be called "virtual.db"

```
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/virtual
```

4.)  Add the following line to `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

```
virtual_alias_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

5.)  Restart postfix:

```
sudo service postfix restart
```

Now all mail, regardless of the sender, recipient or program that points to this SMTP server, will be delivered locally to the specified user.  There are numerous options to read / retrieve these messages now.  If you install an IMAP or POP3 courrier (such as [dovecot](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailServerOverview)), you can use a Mail User Agent (Thunderbird, Outlook, etc.) to connect to your local mailbox and read the messages.

Comment: Make sure that the `<USERNAME>` is mentioned in `etc/aliases`, otherwise you will get errors. Also, if you want to use a Maildir for that user, you must add the lines `home_mailbox = Maildir/` and `mailbox_command = ` to your `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

Answer (score 3):

See another cool approach here [How to catch emails sent with PHP on your local server](http://martinvalasek.com/blog/how-to-catch-emails-sent-with-php-on-your-local-server).

```
$ sudo mkdir /var/log/mail
$ sudo nano /usr/local/bin/sendmail
```

Add following PHP script to this new "sendmail" file:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$input = file_get_contents('php://stdin');
preg_match('|^To: (.*)|', $input, $matches);
$filename = tempnam('/var/log/mail', $matches[1] . '.');
file_put_contents($filename, $input);
```

Add `sendmail_path = /usr/local/bin/sendmail` to `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`.

```
$ sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/sendmail
$ sudo chmod 777 /var/log/mail
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Now all your mails are in `/var/log/mail` folder.

P.S. Also you might want to add `shell_exec("chmod 777 /var/log/mail/ -R");` to `/usr/local/bin/sendmail`

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that you cannot use whatever mail client you have installed to read the mail as the script just dumps the mail in a directory. Being able to serve the mail up via pop3 or imap for example, lets you test your mail in actual mail clients.

Comment: Thank you. I tried your solution too. It worked, thanks! But when I used it I was able to see only emails of user with hostname of MYLOCALUSER. But I wanted to test emails that sent do different accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to run a ["FakeSMTP"](https://nilhcem.github.io/FakeSMTP/) server, a cross platform SMTP handler; who's whole purpose is to receive emails, store and display them with your configured email client.

[image: FakeSMTP Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly a similar environment. But most online documentation about setting up Postfix advise you to choose **Internet Site** during the installation process. I think this is an overkill for a local development server on my machine only. So for me, I do the following

1. Assuming `/etc/hostname` contains `MyDevMachine`; I ensure that `/etc/hosts` contains an entry `127.0.1.1    MyDevMachine`
2. When I install Postfix, I would choose **Local only**, then for the domain setting, I make sure `MyDevMachine` is set.
3. Because I want all emails to be sent to my the development user, and assuming the name of this development user on Ubuntu is `devuser`; I therefore create a file called `/etc/postfix/vmaps`. The content of this file is `/.*/   devuser`. This would allow all emails to be delivered to `devuser`
4. I then run `sudo postmap /etc/postfix/vmaps` that eventually creates `vmaps.db` (sort of activating that virtual mapping).
5. Locate the file `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and append it with following line of code (which will direct Postfix to use the virtual mapping created earlier): `virtual_alias_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/vmaps`
6. Restart Postfix `sudo service postfix restart`