# sendmail that delivers all mail to a directory, storing it separately

Tags: sendmail

I used the configuration [Local only sendmail that delivers all mail to a directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206766/local-only-sendmail-that-delivers-all-mail-to-a-directory), but it is not enough for me.

The solution above store all emails into one file - /var/mail/MYLOCALUSER.
How to store emails separately - one email in one file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this applies to your use case, but I guess you want to configure postfix to use the Maildir format instead of a single file. For my Mail server I followed the Debian Wiki Article: http://wiki.debian.org/Postfix#Maildir

Comment: Yes, just configure the postfix as Maildir format is enough for me - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixBasicSetupHowto#Setting_Postfix_Support_for_Maildir-style_Mailboxes

Answer (score 0):

Sendmail may use procmail as local mailer (AFAIK It is typical on Linux).

Procmail can be configured to deliver to directory (maildir or mh) in `~/.procmailrc` or `/etc/procmailrc`.